# ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements." using custom applinks

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader, google-app-indexing

I've tried to upload application to apple store using `Application Loader` include `Associated Domains` in application entitlements but I have an error:

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'applinks:http://XXX.internal/' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp' is not supported."

- I use distribution certificate
- I have checked to `ON` in Associated Domains in App Ids in apple developer
- I have created provisioning profile using app ids (with enabled Associated Domains) and distribution certificate

What can be the problem? I've tried recreate of all certificates, provisioning profiles etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved this issue.
My problem was that I wrote wrong domain name. I had before:

```
applinks: http://something.com
```

and now I have:

```
applinks:something.com
```

And it's working great.

Answer (score 1):

Go to xcode preferences.Accounts. Select your developer account and double click on the team name in the right. You will see all the provisioning profiles there, select anyone and show in finder. Now delete all these files and move to trash.

Now delete your account from the xocde. Quit xcode.
Now reopen xcode and go to preferences and add your developer account. Download all profiles from here.

Now re-try to build. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @edzio27 sorry about that. It worked for me. May be you can ask someone else to look through the steps, maybe you missed a step or something.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else stumbling across this, the problem is actually in your app ID so just deleting your provisioning profiles won't solve anything. Here's how to fix it:

```
1. Login into your apple developer account
2. Choose certificates and provisioning
3. Click on App ID
4. Click on the edit button for that App ID
5. Turn off Associated Domains
6. Save
```

This will invalidate your existing provisioning profiles so click over to Provisioning Profiles and you'll see the little icons showing the old ones are now invalid.  Delete those. Generate new ones, download those and rebuild your app.

Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when check [image]

app id Push Notifications Disabled  and project ON Notifications Im off Notifcation The problem was solved
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Turning Associated Domains in capabilities off and then back on solved it for me.